# iframe / back button not updating location.href

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Back and forward button controls the iFrame as I want it to.

I am using onClick functions to update the source of the element of the iFrame.

```
<input class='home_main_submenu2' type='button' value='Training Information'  OnClick='document.getElementById("home_frame").src=("http://claytonpolicetraining.blogspot.com/")'>
<input class='home_main_submenu2' type='button' value='Training Resource'  OnClick='document.getElementById("home_frame").src=("/ftproot/TrainingResource/")'>

<iframe id='home_frame' class='viewPort' src='?subtopic=featured_video' name='content_frame'></iframe>
```

I am using a button to "pop out" the iFrame to a new window in case the user doesn't want to use the iFrame. Button code:

```
<input id='frame_new_tab' type='button' value='Open in New Tab' onClick='OpenNewTab("home_frame")'>

function OpenNewTab(id)
{
    var redirect = "";

    try
    {
        window.event.returnValue = false;
        redirect = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.location.href;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        redirect = document.getElementById(id).src;
    }
    window.open(redirect);
}
```

All of the above is working perfect.

**Problem:**

If I open address1 on my iFrame, and then click the Back button to address2 on my iFrame, and then try to "pop" the iFrame, it pops address1, which I had before I clicked the Back button, not address2 which is the iFrame I am currently on.

Somehow, when I press the back button, the iFrame will show the correct content in the iFrame, but it somehow fails to load the proper information to the iFrame element, such as the src. How do I fix this?

Comment: Post your whole code please !

Comment: Hahaha, well that IS what I am attempting to figure out lol. But I swear to you, that is what it is doing when I click the back button..... lol

Comment: Edited original post to contain the entire code applying to the problem. Thank you for replies.

Comment: `iframe.src` is not `iframe.location.href`. The Back button reloads a previous page to the `iframe`, the main page is not updated, and the value you've set to the `src` is still there. You've to assign `iframe.location.href` to get the real page within `iframe`, which is not possible with cross-domain pages though.

Comment: ok, so the problem only occurs when I go from a "primarypage" that is local and back to a "secondarypage" that is external.

Comment: mmm, I think I understand what you are saying, but then is {location.href} the only way to get the url of the iFrame? it seems that if the iFrame is showing a page, I should be able to at least get the url of that page.